# how to add limit in GROUP by clause

Tags: mysql, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

I have to implement a functionality where I have to show answers of question and some comments on that answer, like stackoverflow.

**Currently there are 4 comments in each answer but I want to limit the group by to take 2 comments from each answer.LIMIT will work for entire results.**

```
SELECT ans.answer_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(comm.comment_id) AS comment_ids

FROM `questions_answers` AS ans 
JOIN `questions_answers_comments` AS comm
ON comm.answer_id = ans.answer_id

GROUP BY ans.answer_id LIMIT 100
```

```
answer_id   comment_ids     
1           1,2,3,4
2           5,6,7,8
3           9,10,11,12
4           16,13,14,15
```

Comment: I linked to an answer about limiting groups to four rows per group, but the method is the same whether you want four or two or any other number of rows per group.

Comment: you use https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=53380587f711a8f369b2725f8914e660